# triggering CSS animation with useRef() in React

Tags: css, reactjs, use-ref

i am having a bit of a question with useRef in React.

i am utilizing useRef() to manipulate the properties of some of the button elements in my React application menu. I just want the menu buttons to fade out and disappear as i scroll down the page, so they get out of the way. Quite a classic behavior nothing fancy

it sort of works, but as soon as the button has finished its fadeOut animation, it becomes visible again, i am not sure why...

here is my codeSandbox, so you can see what it looks like :
[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/77w07?file=/src/components/Navbar/Navbar.jsx)

thanks to anyone who cares to help !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to define the [animationFillMode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_animationfillmode.asp) property to `forwards` if you want to persist the animation effect.

include the following to your code:

```
themeButton.current.style.animationFillMode = "forwards";
```

Comment: yes that works and it's cleaner !! i'll look into this !!

Comment: sorry i forgot how i can give you credit for solving my problem on stackOverflow, how do i do this again ? i forgot...

Comment: there is a checkmark next to the answer to accept it as the correct answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work